# HttpPost using Spring RestTemplate fails during load test after some time

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I make a HTTP POST request using Spring RestTemplate which works as expected. However when I do a load test with 10 users using SoapUI, I see

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset exceptions.

Below is the snippet of the code and stack trace for any subsequent calls to the service:

```
final RestTemplate template = getTemplate();
template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
template.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, token);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
try {
    logger.info("Calling DC Flow for requested communication");
    response = template.postForEntity(dcUrl, xml, byte[].class);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    logger.error("hex1--- " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Console screen:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407)
        at test.stream.controller.TestController.testRequest(TestController.java:186)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.jav
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.j
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:7
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what does load test mean? 400 indicates that your request is wrong, do you use postForEntity() to send a get request?

Comment: load test in this context basically is to have multiple threads hit the service. it is a post request and works fine before the load test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You catch error, because your Tomcat application server reachs max Number of threads in Thread pool (it maybe default value).

**Solution 1**

Open file `%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml`, looking for these lines

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

(I am using Apache Tomcat 8.5.9). Add more properties about number of connection: `acceptCount`, `maxConnections` enough for your purpose. For example:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="420" acceptCount="142"/>
```

Read more: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation

**Solution 2**

Since you are using Spring Boot, you can change value of this line

```
server.tomcat.max-threads = 0 # number of threads in protocol handler
```

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because in spring boot the following message converter is enabled by default. Removing this line fixed the issue

template.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());